# Shortcut in VIM to enter in write mode and move the cursor to the line on top?

Tags: vim

Any shortcut to make the cursor go one time on top of the line where I'm currently writing and enter insert mode, without creating any extra line?

Like if i pressed the 'o' key while in command mode but instead of entering insert mode on the bottom line just enter on the line on top.

What I'm looking for is to get what Alt+O would do, but instead of making a new line just go above the current line without making any new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can just press `k` to go one line above. Then press

- `i` if you want to insert where you are,
- `I` if you want to insert at the beginning of the of the line or
- `A`  if you want to insert at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you want to jump to the beginning of the line above and go into insert mode. To achieve that I suggest doing it literally step by step:

<kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

here <kbd>k</kbd> will move you one line up and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> jump to the beginning of the line and go into insert mode.

Comment: Hi Tarek! I really appreciate your answer and the advice, but it's not quite what i was searching for. I don't want to create an extra while space line above the line i'm currently at, i want the cursor to go to the line above without creating any extra line. Even so, thank you! I'm just starting with Vim

Comment: Hi @Gabri, thanks for the clarification, and welcome to VIM world. Please edit your question to be more specific. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `<c-g>k` or `<c-o>O`:

```
CTRL-G k    cursor one line up, insert start column      *i_CTRL-G_k*
CTRL-G CTRL-K   cursor one line up, insert start column      *i_CTRL-G_CTRL-K*
CTRL-O      execute one command, return to Insert mode   *i_CTRL-O*
```